# My Weblogic's soft limit and hard limit is same

Tags: linux, weblogic, ulimit

in Linux, I test about `ulimit` and WebLogic. I set soft limit and hard limit differently, but process's soft limit and hard limit is same. Why they have same value?

```
# Set Soft limit
[was@was10 bin]$ ulimit –S -n 2048
# Check Soft limit
[was@was10 bin]$ ulimit -S -a
……
open files                      (-n) 2048
……
# Check Hard limit
[was@was10 bin]$ ulimit -H -a
……
open files                      (-n) 4096
……
# restart Weblogic and check limits
[was@was10 bin]$ cat /proc/$PID/limits
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units
……
Max open files            4096                 4096                 files
……
# They have same value 4096
```

- CentOS 7
- `/etc/security/limits.conf` is default.
- `cat /etc/security/limits.d/*.conf`

```
*          soft    nproc     4096
root       soft    nproc     unlimited
```

Answer (score 0):

I find about it.

It is because of MaxFDLimit.

Thanks

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).